# Facebook Like Button Not Posting To Feed For Non FB Application Devs

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to get a simple facebook like setup along with a dynamic link for videos.  The video functionality (publishVidToFB()) below works great!  However I can't get this infernal "Like" to work for anyone but me.

The app is not in sandbox mode.  Likes work fine for me, but my comments aren't coming through.  For other devs here who aren't setup as "Facebook Developers" on the App - likes aren't showing up for them at all on their newsfeeds.

The FB debugger isn't complaining about anything but the image size in the og:image tag.

Please see code below and please do help!

*!DOCTYPE html*

*html*

```
*head*

    *meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id is here" *
    *meta property="og:url" content="link back to the originating page is here... "*
    *meta property="og:site_name" content="site name code is here like 'INTERNALCODE'"*
    *meta property="og:image" content="web linkable image is here"*
    *meta property="og:description" content="description blah blah."*
    *meta property="og:type" content="company"*
    *meta property="og:title" content="blah blah blah"*
*/head*
*body*
    *div id="fb-root"**/div*
    *input type="button" value="Publish" onclick="publishVidToFB(); return false;" *
    *script*

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'my appid is here', // App ID
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


        function publishVidToFB(){
            FB.ui({
               method: "stream.publish",
               user_message_prompt: "",
               message: "message",
               attachment: {
                  name: "Check out this cool video",
                  caption: "Video caption goes here etc etc etc",
                  href: "my href is here",
                  media:[{
                      "type": "image", 
                      "src": "image source is here",
                      "href": "myhref is here"
                    }]
                }
            });
        };

    */script*
    *div class="fb-like" data-href="href is here" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"**/div*
*/body*
```

*/html*

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Facebook had blacklisted the app for all of my testing.  Waited a few days, worked on other issues, and we're up and running.